# Where is the Chebyshev function of the second kind in Mathematica/Alpha?

Tags: functions, number-theory

I need to perform some computations involving the Chebyshev function of the second kind (sometimes also called the **summatory Von Mangoldt function**)  $\psi(x)$, defined as $$\psi(x) = \sum_{n\le x} \Lambda(n)$$

where $\Lambda(n)$ denotes the Von Mangoldt function. However, I am having trouble finding this function in Wolfram Mathematica* as well as in Wolfram Alpha, despite reading a large amount of documentation. Is this function included in the Wolfram language?

---

*I am using version 11.1

Comment: What's wrong with `ψ[x_]  := Sum[MangoldtLambda[n], {n, 2, x}]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll So there is no built-in function for it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @CarlWoll Then add it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe the Chebyshev function you want is built-in to Mathematica. On the other hand, you can program it naively as:

```
ψ[x_] := Sum[MangoldtLambda[n], {n, 2, x}]
```

However, this function is rather slow. A much faster alternative is to use:

```
ψ2[x_] := Sum[Plus @@ Log[Prime @ Range @ PrimePi[x^(1/n)]], {n,Floor[N@Log[2, x]]}]
```

A speed comparison:

```
r1 = ψ[10^5]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = ψ2[10^5]; //AbsoluteTiming
r1 === r2
```

> {4.6993, Null}
>
> {0.059376, Null}
>
> True

And, an example with an even larger argument:

```
ψ2[10^7]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.49548, Null}

Comment: Thank you, that's the perfect answer

Comment: You can replace `Floor[N @ Log[2, x]]` with `IntegerLength[x, 2] - 1`.